# docker-compose how to add multiple command?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, command

I wrote "docker-compose.yml", and I want to execute two commands:
`uwsgi -i /code/uwsgi.ini` and `python3.6 /code/manage.py collectstatic`

I tried to use `&&` to connect the two command, but it failed, what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute multiple commands using `bash -c`:

```
command: >
    bash -c "uwsgi -i /code/uwsgi.ini
    && python3.6 /code/manage.py collectstatic"
```